# XWiki failing to initialize

Tags: mysql, tomcat, ubuntu-16.04, xwiki

So long story short, we had our XWiki server go down recently because someone merged some snapshots they shouldn't have, and it broke something. Chased my tail for a few hours until I realized it was pointless, and just started with fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.

Installed everything fine, hit localhost:8080/xwiki and it pulled up the content manager starting pages like it should. Then I pulled my backed up mysql dump from mozy, and merged it via:

```
mysql -u xwiki -p xwiki < mysql.backup
```

Pointed to localhost:8080/xwiki and I could see my data, but it just seemed rediculously slow. Tried clicking on some pages, and they wouldn't even load. Now when I try to go back, it gets stuck at "XWiki is initializing 50%" and won't get any further. I've already looked at their performance page, and increased tomcat's memory allocation to 1024m, but no dice.

I've looked in the /var/log/tomcat & mysql but there is no pertinent info in there. Is there any place else I can look for info on why this is happening? Has anyone else run into this type of issue?

Any help is much appreciated, I posted 4-5 days ago over on xwiki forums, but no response whatsoever, so I'm reaching out to you guys as a last hope.

**Details (Virtual Machine):**
OS: 32bit Ubuntu 16.04
RAM: 4GB
Package: xwiki-enterprise-tomcat7-mysql
Java: openjdk-7-jre-headless

Comment: Actually the /var/log/tomcat directory usually should contain information what XWiki is doing, unless you modified the WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml to log elsewhere, but then you sure know where to look. Have you tried to get a thread dump of the java process running XWiki? This should give you a hint what keeps the server is busy.

Comment: I have not, what is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Nvm, got it, tomcat was crashing due to OutOfMemory issue. Resolved with a few JAVA_OPT params. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! If you want to set that as answer I'll mark as correct.

Comment: Well, what I said was not an answer. You can self answer your question by listing the JAVA_OPT options that were successful. Sure they should have been set up that way from the start, or maybe the documentation of the XWiki site is incomplete with regard to this.